# React Native, iOS, trying `yarn run ios` and I get RCTAppDelegate.h not found

Tags: ios, react-native

Trying to build a React Native iOS app, and while I got it running fine using Android, trying to get it running on iOS has been a bit of a nightmare.

I created this base react native app, back in Sept 2022, doing the typical `npx react-native init <projectname>` and was working on android mostly (I use a linux box, and I have to use Teamviewer to connect to a mac to build the iOS apps).

I had my app working fine in android and iOS, and then added the Zoom Video SDK and everything went to hell. Got it working fine in Android, and tried to take my changes and build them in iOS but I couldn't get it to work, and seemingly got my iOS project corrupted, so I tried to create a fresh iOS project, by basically created a same-named project in a different directory, and replacing the **`<projectname>/ios`** with the new base ios project.

Of course, I did this Jan 2023, so it's the new architecture, and the AppDelegate.h tries to import the **RCTAppDelegate.h** file instead of React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h

I do my usual `yarn install` go into the ios directory and `pod install` and then try to do a `yarn run ios` and it tells me it can't find **RCTAppDelegate.h**

Anyone solve this yet?  The React-Native docs aren't up to date with their github repo

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, i solved it by opening the **.xcworkspace** instead of opening **.xcodeproj**
I also cleaned the build folder by

*Product --> Clean Build folder*

and then it successfully built the app.

Comment: Tried that myself and that didn't work... I ended up getting it to work using the old architecture, but there are WAY too many steps to list here (the Zoom Developer forums have more info)

Comment: @DanPiccolo i am struggling with it from few days can you help me in it?